Jasper Report not rendering special characters
Currently working on dispatch note template,
having a problem with displaying special symbols (š,č,ť,ž,ň, and so on - slovak localization) from resource bundle (.properties)... encoding is initialized properly.
Tried - markup="html", isStyledText="true"
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding" value="Cp1250"/>

Current state :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.6.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.6-5c96b6aa8a39ac1dc6b6bea4b81168e16dd39231  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="DispatchNote" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>


DON'T try to hard-code any codepages. This is causing the problem. This page is UTF8 and has no problems displaying those characters. No special conversion was performed to display them, as Stack Overflow is a .NET application storing text in nvarchar fields. Strings in both .NET and Java are Unicode only.

Solution that worked was to add pdfEncoding="Cp1250" directly on the font tag within the textElement>textField, which I did not have defined before, since I was using default values
